# Свой Maven репозиторий на GitHub

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Deploy на GitHub настроил как сказано [здесь](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-maven-repository-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github/).

После обновления Idea, перестало работать.
Точнее deploy происходит без ошибок, а вот подтянуть потом к себе в проект не могу. Пишет:

```
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerIndexerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
```

Этого файла и действительно нет, но раньше же работало и без него.
Что это за файл и как его создавать?

Comment: Вам удалось победить этот плагин и сделать свой репозиторий? Не поделитесь опытом? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283155/Создать-свой-maven-repository-на-github